# Как настроить mercurial сервер с доступом по ssh на CentOS 5.*?

Tags: mercurial, контроль-версий, ssh, centos

Как настроить mercurial сервер с доступом по ssh на CentOS 5.*?

Answer (score 1):

Ничего не надо настраивать. Надо просто сделать этот ssh-доступ. Плюс надо разобраться с unix-пользователями, чтобы у них хватало прав изменять файлы.

Также может потребоваться настройка доверенных пользователей. Для этого прочтите [мануал по hgrc в разделе trusted](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hgrc.5.html#trusted) - это будет работать, если вы не включаете модуль ACL.

Comment: Нужно поставить mercurial или mercurial-server?

Comment: Я не знаю что такое mercurial-server :( Есть один mercurial. Это какая-то специфика cent os. Я думаю, что если не ставить mercurial-server, то вы всё равно сможете использовать его по SSH, потому что mercurial - децентрализованная VCS.